# How to bind a property of control to another control's property

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I have two controls on my form(control1 and control2) that are located next to the each other.
The width of control1 is variable.

Can I bind the Left Property of control2 to the width property of control1?

I wrote below code but it didn't work:

```
control2.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Left", control1, "Width"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
control2.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Left", control1, "Width"));//Your code
```

Your code doesn't work because there is no change notification going when chaning `Width` property, but `Size` does.

You can bind to `Size` but the problem is you need an `int` but Size property is of type `Size`, so you need to convert it also using [Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event like this.

```
var binding = new Binding("Left", control1, "Size", true,DataSourceUpdateMode.Never);
binding.Format += (sender, args) =>
{
    if (args.DesiredType == typeof (int))
    {
        Size size = (Size) args.Value;
        args.Value = size.Width;
    }
};
control2.DataBindings.Add(binding);
```

Another way is to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your source control. That should do the trick.

Comment: @HamidReza Care to explain what doesn't work. I tested before posting it worked. Update your question with updated code.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
control2.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Left", control1, "Width"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

I look more deeper and it has three options

```
public enum DataSourceUpdateMode
{
  OnValidation,
  OnPropertyChanged,
  Never
}
```

Default is OnValidation, but the Width doesn't cause neither Validation neither PropertyChanged

An example of usage:

```
   panel1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Width", panel2, "Width", false,  DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

Comment: It is a Winform app, you don't required to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: @Anuraj He is correct. What makes you to think Winform app doesn't need `INotifyPropertyChanged`? It is first introduced for winforms only in .net2.0. Refer my answer for more info.

Comment: If you want to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for binding in Winforms, how it was working before .net 2.0? Binding class available in .net 1.1 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.Binding(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @SriramSakthivel also how we will implement INotifyPropertyChanged in controls in Windows form standard controls?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel The code works perfectly fine for me. I think the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Anuraj Not all properties can be done, but `Width` is possible. Te be specific for all virtual properties we can do that. Note that Winform controls provide change notification in different way via `SizeChanged`, `VisibleChanged` etc,

Comment: How can I use INotifyPropertyChanged? I'm almost beginner in C#.

Comment: @HamidReza you are sure it is not working? can you try other overloads of binding class? one like this? - button1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("left", button2, "width", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, null, null));

Answer (score 0):

You can do that. Here is a snippet in this I am binding trackbar value to width of button

```
button1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("width", trackBar1, "value"));
```

I tried with Textbox also, it is also working.

```
button1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("left", textBox1, "Text"));
```

Comment: Anuraj, You're missing the fact that `Text` works because there is an event called `TextChanged` op is trying `Width`, there is no event called `WidthChanged` so it doesn't work. That's why I suggested alternate solution which effectively does the same with `Size` it will work because we have `SizeChanged` event. Is that clear?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I tried the following code, in that I am modifying the width using trackbar value and left is by width and it works.

button1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("left", button2, "width"));
button2.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("width", trackBar1, "value"));

Comment: No what am talking is other way around. You are binding `Width` from `Value` that will work because we have `ValueChanged` event. What op trying is to bind `Left` **from Width**.

Comment: I understand, I have two bindings, one for width which is using value, other one is left which is using width, both are working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to handle this I think is by EventHandlers:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        panel2.SizeChanged +=panel2_SizeChanged;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel2.Size = new Size(panel2.Size.Width * 2, panel2.Size.Height * 2);
    }

    void panel2_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Size = panel2.Size;
    }
```